# in jQuery, what is the difference between $("div") and $("<div>")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code in a book which reads:

```
function hit()
{
    var $d = $("<div>");
    $d.addClass("current_hand")
      .appendTo("#my_hand");
}
```

I know that `$("div")` will select all the div elements. However what does `$("<div>")` do? Does it create a new div element? If so, is this the standard way of creating new DOM elements in jQuery, or are there other ways?

Comment: with `$("<div>")` you create a div element

Comment: maybe you should read the jquery documentation before asking..?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in jQuery, what is the difference between `$("div")` and `$("<div>")`?

[`$("div")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) finds all existing `div` elements in the document.

[`$("<div>")`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) *creates* a `div` element, which you'd then append to the document at some stage (presumably).

> If so, is this the standard way of creating new DOM elements in jQuery, or are there other ways?

Fairly standard, yes. Other ways of creating elements include adding HTML content to any existing element (via [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) or [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before) or [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) or any of a large number of other functions).